# How woocommerce products,categories and subcategories are translate into other language?

Tags: wordpress

How I can translate WooCommerce product and categories into other language.
We have the WordPress default function:

```
define(WP_LANG,'');
```

I have set:

```
define (WP_LANG,'heIL');
```

It changes all WordPress content but does not change WooCommerce product name categories.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make your Wordpress site or store multilingual you have to use some third party plugin like [WPML](http://wpml.org/) which takes care of the translation management

Here is an explanation what you need to make your shop multlingual: http://wpml.org/documentation/related-projects/woocommerce-multilingual/

Hope it helps.

Comment: Do know any non-paid plugin or customization in wordpress ?

Comment: Unfortunately i don't think that there's an free translation plugin. We only used Woocommerce in connection with WPML.

Comment: Is there any other method or fundamental thatt can help me.

Comment: As @WisdmLabs suggests, you could try [qLabs](https://wordpress.org/plugins/qtranslate/) and see if it fit your needs.

Comment: have you use this pluin before in your project or any one know much about its implementation

Answer (score 0):

See here the listings of some popular translation plugins http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/top-6-translation-plugins-for-your-wordpress-site/

There are free plugins too, however they are not as much powerful as WPML. But, see if they can help.

[qTranslate](https://wordpress.org/plugins/qtranslate/) is one of the mostly used free plugin among these.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is a translation plugin. There are many of them but I am using WPML and it is going well. You have to install it and you will have access to translate all blog.

I let you this plugin http://ul.to/qjl85490